# Justify $\mathbb{Q}\simeq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ as groups

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

Recently I was studying automorphism of groups, and I found that ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Q})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^\ast$. I have proved it. I also showed if two groups are isomorphic then so are their automorphism groups.

After this I moved on to check if ${\rm Aut}(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}])\simeq \mathbb{Q}^\ast$ as groups. For this purpose, I was curious to show if $\mathbb{Q}\simeq \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is true but got stuck. How can I show this?

Comment: Hint: for every two rationals $a,b$, there is a nonzero couple of integers $(n,m)$ such that $na=mb$. Is this the same for $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$?

Comment: If $G$ is isomorphic to $H$ then $Aut(G)$ is isomorphic to $Aut(H)$, but the converse does not hold. If $Aut(G) = Aut(H)$ then both options: $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic and $G$ and $H$ are not isomorphic are still on the table.

Comment: As additive groups $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2]\simeq \Bbb{Q}^2$, so $Aut(\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt2])\simeq GL_2(\Bbb{Q})$, no?

Comment: The title states something wrong. Are you perhaps confusing this with the topic of [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961409/showing-textaut-mathbbq-is-the-trivial-group-and-calculating-textaut)? This is about field automorphisms.

Comment: A set by itself is not a group. To define a group you also have to specify an operation

Comment: Careful reading of the post shows that the OP wondered about whether $\mathbb Q \simeq \mathbb Q[\sqrt 2]$, and the previous remarks are context for that problem.  Of course there is the issue of whether these are additive groups, but as $\sqrt 2$ is irrational, I see no difficulty in asking for proof or disproof of the claim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't show any of your last two statements, both are false.

First $\mathbb{Q}$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ as groups. That's because given two $\mathbb{Q}$-linear spaces $A$, $B$ these are isomorphic as groups if and only if they are isomorphic as $\mathbb{Q}$-linear spaces. And $\mathbb{Q}$ has dimension $1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ while $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is of dimension $2$.

Secondly $\rm Aut(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}])$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}^*$. Indeed, $\mathbb{Q}^*$ has exactly two elements of finite order, namely $1$ and $-1$. While $\rm Aut(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}])$ has more, at least three: $$f_1(x)=x$$
$$f_2(x)=-x$$
$$f_3(a+b\sqrt{2})=b+a\sqrt{2}$$